# The newcomer learns the knn algorithm and hopes to help solve a small problem

Tags: python

## the code

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=666)

neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)

neigh.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predict = neigh.predict(X_test)`
print(sum(y_predict == y_test) / len(y_test))
```

## my question

I don't know why the result is 1.0,and if I change the test_size,the result is also 1.0.
I hope someone can help answer, thank you

Comment: By result, do you mean the output of the `print(sum(y_predict == y_test) / len(y_test))` line here?

Comment: Yes，print(sum(y_predict == y_test) / len(y_test)),and the result is 1.0,if I change the test_size,the result is also 1.0

Comment: The result is 1 because all your entire test set is predicted correctly.

Comment: I just ran the example with `test_size=0.9`. That way the set you train on it small enough to mess up the model. Try it and you should see the number drop.

Comment: No you're not, lol. Trust me I was worse. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line of your code is accuracy on test set. It tells you how  many percent of predictions are the same as true labels.

If you get `acc=1.0` it means you predict all examples correctly.